# Change Chrome default username/password for a site

Tags: windows, google-chrome, default-settings, credentials

I manage several websites through Bluehost and have all of the usernames/passwords stored in Chrome for ease of login. What I'm wondering is if anyone knows of a way to change which username/password is auto-filled into a website login page on Chrome. For example, if I want to make the default username for logging into Bluehost "foobar.com" because I'm currently working on that site but Chrome auto-fills one of my other sites (e.g., "keanureeves.com") by default. Does anyone know how to change that?